# Reset Entity Framework CodeFirst database after integration tests

Tags: entity-framework, integration-testing, code-first

In my integration tests I can run this

```
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        SeedDb.Init(); //static method that initializes db and seeds with data  
       //public class SeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>
    }
```

but running this same code in a class cleanup doesn't error but doesn't reset the database either. The data in the database is data left from the integration tests.

```
    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void MyClassTearDown()
    {
        SeedDb.Init();
    }
```

I can delete the database in the clean up method but then the call to SeedDb.Init() fails.

```
    Database.Delete(DbConnectionString); //this does delete the database
```

I am disposing of the context in my integration test. Is there a pattern to allow a codefirst reset in a class cleanup method?